# Generate Response from Aspx page

Tags: php, asp.net, arrays

I have a php page which hits an aspx page `http://server/default.aspx?xml=abc` , the file creates a PDF using xml sent in the query string and its stored on .net server.

Now, How can i get bytearray of PDF file thats generated??? I also want to know how to generate the response from aspx

Note: I am done till genrating bytearray in asp

Comment: If the PDF is stored in the server how are you expecting it to send byte array to you?

Comment: I want to know the way it can be sent, I have the byte array genrated just want to generate response to a php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will open a file and write the binary response back to the caller.

```
using(var file = new FileStream("", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
        var byteArray = new byte[file.Length];

        var br = new BinaryReader(file);

        byteArray = br.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);

        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
}
```

Comment: can i acess it through $_POST then ?

Comment: Sorry not overly familiar with php, but basically the response from the page will be a byte array